# Maximizing difference of a submodular and a modular function

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, optimization, submodularity

I'm considering a network planning problem which is stated as follows:
From the given ground set $\mathcal{V}$, select $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{V}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
f(\mathcal{A}) - \sum_{v_i \in \mathcal{A}} c_i
\end{equation}
is maximized where $f$ is a monotone submodular function and $c_i \ge 0$ is the cost of selecting $v_i$. The problem is an instance of nonomonotone submodular maximization for which a local search heuristic with approximation bound of $\frac{2}{5} - \frac{\epsilon}{n}$ is presented in

Uriel Feige, Vahab S. Mirrokni, Jan Vondrák: "Maximizing Non-Monotone Submodular Functions ", FOCS 2007.

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a better approximation algorithm for my specific problem?

Comment: The result of Feige, Mirrokni and Vondrak applies only to non-negative functions. Your function is no guaranteed to be non-negative unless you are making additional assumptions. I guess you meant the approximation in FMS is 2/5, not 2/4. There is an upcoming paper in FOCS 2012 by Buchbinder etal who obtain an optimal 1/2 approximation for non-negative submodular function maximization. Without non-negativity the problem is inapproximable. See the following paper for some related work on your problem. http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1616497.1616507

Comment: Thanks Chandra for your very helpful comment. You were right about the bound. It has been edited.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify life, let $\mathcal V = [n] := \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. For $A \subseteq [n]$, define $h(A):=\sum_{i \in A}c_i$. Note that $h$ defines a modular (i.e additive) set function. Now, suppose there exists $\gamma \in [0, 1]$ such that $f$ is weakly $\gamma$-submodular, i.e such that

$$
\sum_{i \in B\setminus A}f(A \cup \{i\}) - f(A)  \ge \gamma (f(A \cup B) - f(A)),\;\forall A,B \subseteq [n].
$$

Then, greedy maximization produces a subset $A^G$  with $k$ elements such that

$$
f(A^G)-h(A^G) \ge (1-e^{-\gamma})f(A^*)-h(A^*),
$$

where $A^*$ is the $k$-element subset of $[n]$ which maximizes $f(A)-h(A)$.
This is a direct consequence of [Theorem 3 of this ICML paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/harshaw19a/harshaw19a-supp.pdf).

Comment: See also  more recent paper. https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.07782

Answer (score 0):

See recent work [Unconstrained Submodular Maximization with Modular Costs:
Tight Approximation and Application to Profit Maximization.](http://vldb.org/pvldb/vol14/p1756-jin.pdf)
 It provides both lower and upper bound for your problem. It seems that from Theorem 1 and 2, their algorithm is optimal!

Comment: Welcome to Theoretical Computer Science! While this link may answer the question, it [is better](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/295232) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or disappears.